# Objectify with Endpoints for android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I read that Objectify is a supported framework for use with Endpoints.
How do I convert the sample from the GPE App Engine Connected Android Project wizard to deal with Objectify 4 data?

I'm getting this:

org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: 
The class "com.example.MyObjectifyTestInfo" is not persistable. 
This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

I have searched a lot, but found nothing in stackoverflow or elsewhere.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datanucleus (as in org.datanucleus...) is the JDO/JPA library, so that message indicates that you still have JDO/JPA artificacts in your project.  The message is correct - now that you are using objectify your class is not persistable using datanucleus, so what is still trying?

I would suggest that you review your project settings and your class file's import statements to make sure you've removed all JDO/JPA.

Comment: The endpoint class generated by the GPE is dependent on JDO/JPO, it certainly has at least 1 import from it, which is com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Cursor. To remove this I'd have to mess with the autogenerated methods.

Comment: actually, the import is com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPACursorHelper

Comment: Though endpoints support Ofy (and many people use it), the auto-generate is for JDO/JPA, so you will need to mess with the auto-generated code if you want to switch.  Unless you plan to use both, which could be rather messy.

Comment: Tom, 2 questions:
1 isn't auto-generation the main advantage of endpoints ?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4

2 Under  GPE this uses JPA. Is there a sample that doesn't use JPA?

I tried removing datanucleus in AppEngine settings, & added javaee-api-7.0.jar for JPA.
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() now fails to get a Persistence provider for EntityManager. I tried changing the persistence provider in persistence.xml to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider, but that didn't help.

Comment: Ok, I removed all JPA and autogenerated endpoints and the client libs autogenerate & the ofy persistence seems ok so far. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any auto-generate of Ofy endpoinnts, but for me, while the auto-generate of the client libs is a key part of endpoints, the auto-generate of the endpoints is not so important.

Comment: @timmacp auto-generation in the context of client libraries is a selling point of Endpoints. Generation of example code in GPE is a neat thing that we offer, but applicable only to a limited subset of users. (Most people will want to modify the API; use a different persistence layer, runtime, or IDE; or some combination of these.)