# Generating Endpoints class from objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

As stated in the title, is there a way of doing this using Google Plugin for eclipse?

I tried to generate it using Generate Cloud Endpoints class in GPE, I got this error in appengine log:

```
org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager loadPersistenceUnit: Class com.UserDataEndpoint was specified in persistence-unit transactions-optional but not annotated, so ignoring
```

All the classes I generate using "Generate Cloud Endpoints class" have this error, and can't do any transactions in the API Explorer.

I read in other thread of Stackoverflow, but there is no clear guide on doing this correctly, so I opened a new thread.

Thank you

EDIT : I forgot to mention that I'm using GPE App Engine Connected Android Project wizard to deal with Objectify 5

Comment: Can you post the link of the "other thread of Stackoverflow" ?

Comment: The most relevant is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938434/objectify-with-endpoints-for-android?rq=1
tom's answer
I'm still confused, because there's no errors when GPE plugin generates the Endpoint class. What I get from tom's answer is that the generated codes are still using JDO annotation which won't work with objectify

Comment: Is there different annotations for Endpoint Class for database using Objectify?